# JavaFX QuantumRenderer initializing Error

Tags: java, javafx

Beginning Info:

- JavaFX 18.0.1 (x64 sdk)
- Opdenjdk 1.8.0_322
- Operating System: Windows
- Using Visual Studio Code

I'm creating my first JavaFX Project right now. And i'm facing an error

> Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
> Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

for a few hours now. I read most other SO posts about that problem and tried various solutions including:

1. Reinstalling the JavaFX jdk
2. Tryout to install JavaFX jmods instead of JDK
3. Make sure that it is the x64 instead of x86 and for the right operating system
4. Creating a module-info.java which gave me a new error

   ```
    javafx.graphics cannot be resolved to a module
   ```

That should not be there because I added all libraries in the correct way for `VisualStudio` (I think so). This error is gone with removing the `module-info.java`.

[image: Modules]

5. Adding a line `launch.json` (Was to solve a other problem though)

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
```

And some other, which I forgot what it was.

But nothing of the things mentioned above helped. Someone got ideas?

**--UPDATE--**

I may know now what the Problem is. But not how to solve it.

If i change the Referenced Libraries from JavaFX 18.0.1 to any other Version, the Error keeps saying that the problems come from 18.0.1 Files. Even if those were removed from the Project. I tried to create a new Project and only Reference JavaFX 11, but the Error still talks about Errors in FX 18.0.1 Files, even if those arent even added to that Project in any way.

[image: Wrong Version of FX]

Could that be the Problem? If yes, how can I fix it?

App.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
  
  Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
  
  primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

module-info.java

```
module FirstJavaFXProject_bacc5c93 {

    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.web;
    requires javafx.swing;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens App;
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Java",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "classpath": [
                ".",
                "${fileDirname}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Java Console App",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "classpath": [
                ".",
                "${fileDirname}"
            ],
            "externalConsole": true
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch App",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "App",
            "projectName": "FirstJavaFXProject_bacc5c93",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Java/javafx-sdk-18.0.1/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
$ java -version
openidk version "1.8.0 322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.60.0.21-CA-win64) (build 1.8.0 322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.60.0.21-CA-win64) (build 25.322-b06, mixed
```

Comment: I think you should make sure that the JDK version matches the JavaFX version. Your code runs fine for me on Windows 10 with Oracle JDK 18.0.1 and OpenJFX 18.0.1 (all three are 64 bit). Note that there are JDKs that include JavaFX such as [Azul Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk)

Comment: Hey @Abra, i edited the Question and added the full java -version command output. Could you tell me if that ZULU Version includes JavaFX. And if yes, what are the next steps then?

Comment: Javafx 18 requires java 11+ https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/jfx18/doc-files/release-notes-18.md

Comment: Besides if you use jdk8 you don't need any `jpms` manipulations like `module-info` and vm-args with module path

Comment: The Zulu builds with JavaFX are recent ones (e.g. 18.0.1) and in the download, you must choose `JDK FX`, not `JDK`, for the "Java Package" as Zulu calls it.  The prepackaged system is an alternative to depending on JavaFX via downloaded mods, JavaFX SDK or build system (maven/gradle) JavaFX dependencies. It does not require specific module settings for the VM runtime and compilation steps.  It is a reasonable option for getting started quickly for a project you develop on your own. For a shared project, it is probably better to have JavaFX dependent modules in a maven or gradle build.

Comment: @Alex are you sure? The module-info gave me new Errors so i agree with that. But after i added the vm-args it fixed a Error i hat before.

Comment: @trashgod what Text do you need?

Comment: Lets start with that you are trying to use incompatible libs. As mentioned before - javafx 18 requires java 11+. It won't work with java 8 at all

Comment: @Alex the thing is that this Pc is one of my Company, so the Java Version is pre installed and normaly not changable cause of restrictions. So my Question is, which Version of JavaFX do i need to make it work with Java 8, and would i loose access to much features cause of that downgrade?

Comment: You can use openjfx 11 https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ for java 8

Comment: @Alex i tried it out with JavaFX 11, 11.0.1 and 11.0.2. None of them Changed anything. Still the same Error. So what to do now?

Comment: then you have to go the other way round and use javafx8 - there is no way to mix

Comment: @kleopatra so i cant use (like Alex mentioned above) Fx 11 for Java 8? It is needed that both are in the exact same Version? (Like: Java 8 and Fx 8)

Comment: in your case, yes (all versions javafx >= 11 can be run with jdk11)

Comment: @kleopatra so where i Find JavaFx 8? At the official JavaFx Website (openjfx.io) I only find JavaFx 11-18 but no Version under 11.

Comment: JavaFX 8 is in Oracle JDK 8, which you don't have, you have Zulu 8 which (apparently) doesn't include JavaFX.  There is no download or install to add JavaFX to Zulu 8.  You could find an old OpenJFX source branch and try to [build a binary version that would run with Zulu 8](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX), but I definitely would not at all recommend that . . . don't even try.